# Javascript array - use of variable as key

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve an array value where the key is a variable. JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Fap/) -- type 'apparel' or 'books' into the industry input. The output of the JSFiddle states that the value returned is undefined.

The problem lies in `var filename = constants.factsheet` - how can I correctly pass the value of factsheet to retrieve the associated filename?

JS:

```
  $(function () {

      var availableIndustries = ["apparel", "books"];

      $("#industry").autocomplete({
          source: availableIndustries
      });

      $("input[type=image]")
          .button()
          .click(function (event) {

          var constants = {
              'apparel': 'apparel.pdf',
                  'books': 'publishing.pdf',
          };

          var factsheet = document.getElementById('industry').value;
          var filename = constants.factsheet;
          $('#factsheet').text('Your factsheet is ' + factsheet);
          $('#file').text('Your filename is ' + filename);

      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var filename = constants.factsheet;
```

to:

```
var filename = constants[factsheet];
```

(Note that your `constants` is not an array. It's an object.)

In JavaScript, you can access object properties in two ways: Using dot notation and a literal property name (`constants.apparel`), or using bracketed notation and a string property name (`constants["apparel"]`). In the second case, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup. So these all show the same thing:

```
// Dot notation
console.log(constants.apparel);

// Brackets with string literal
console.log(constants["apparel"]);

// Brackets with concatentation expression
console.log(constants["app" + "arel"]);

// Brackets using a variable
var name = "apparel";
console.log(constants[name]);

// Brackets using the return value of a function
function foo() { return "apparel"; }
console.log(constants[foo()]);
```

You get the idea.

Comment: The additional explanation is much appreciated, thanks very much TJ.

Answer (score 1):

T.J. Crowder is right about using bracket syntax for looking-up objects by a variable key name, I just optimized things a bit by moving your static files object constant out of the event function (no need to generate that each time), and cached the `#industry` element reference.

```
$(function () {

  var industryInput = $('#industry'),
      availableIndustries = ['apparel', 'books'],
      files = {
          'apparel': 'apparel.pdf',
          'books': 'publishing.pdf'
      };

  industryInput.autocomplete({
      source: availableIndustries
  });

  $('input[type=image]').button().click(function (event) {
      var factsheet = industryInput.value;
      $('#factsheet').text('Your factsheet is ' + factsheet);
      $('#file').text('Your filename is ' + files[factsheet]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I post the above answer the way it applies to you in your code.

```
  $(function () {

      var availableIndustries = ["apparel", "books"];

      $("#industry").autocomplete({
          source: availableIndustries
      });

      $("input[type=image]")
          .button()
          .click(function (event) {

          var constants = {
              'apparel': 'apparel.pdf',
                  'books': 'publishing.pdf',
          };

          var factsheet = document.getElementById('industry').value;
          var filename = constants[factsheet];
          $('#factsheet').text('Your factsheet is ' + factsheet);
          $('#file').text('Your filename is ' + filename);

      });
  });
```